# Cannot mount my Storage Gateway filesystem using OCI Storage Gateway

Tags: oracle, cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to mount a local folder to a File System created within OCI Storage Gateway Management Console

I created the filesystem based on the documentation: https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/StorageGateway/Tasks/creatingyourfirstfilesystem.htm
When I try to mount it using this command from local host nothing happens for minutes

The mount command I executed: 
`sudo mount -t nfs -o vers=4,port=32770 <ip address>:/SG-Test /home/opc/ocisg/`

Instead of a successful mount, I get an error message:
`mount.nfs: Connection timed out`

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue maybe?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Although the documentation only asks to open the management console port using security list rules, but I had to add 2 other ports: NFS Port and rest port.

Comment: I have to correct myself. It was a coincidence, that opening other ports helped. What really helped is restart of docker.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to restart docker (in which OCI Storage Gateway runs).